# Compiling Microsoft Detours for 64-bit

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, detours

The [`detours`](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours/wiki/OverviewHelpers) package claims to support `64-bit` but I don't see a way to compile `64-bit` binaries:

> Detouring 32-bit and 64-bit Processes

Using `nmake all` compiles only `32-bit` stuff:

```
>dir
 Volume in drive D is Volume
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of D:\Detours

06/21/2018  03:46 PM    <DIR>          .
06/21/2018  03:46 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/23/2018  08:13 PM    <DIR>          bin.X86
06/20/2017  09:03 AM             5,105 CREDITS.TXT
06/22/2017  03:06 PM                31 Detours Version 3.0 Build_343
10/19/2016  12:06 PM           113,685 Detours.chm
06/23/2018  08:12 PM    <DIR>          include
06/23/2018  08:12 PM    <DIR>          lib.X86
10/29/2015  02:19 PM             7,144 LICENSE.RTF
12/21/2016  01:22 PM             1,851 Makefile
06/22/2017  03:06 PM            14,961 README.TXT
06/21/2018  03:04 PM    <DIR>          samples
06/23/2018  08:12 PM    <DIR>          src
10/29/2015  02:19 PM             4,841 system.mak
06/22/2017  03:06 PM                31 VERSION.TXT
```

The `nmake size64` command is invalid.

If I use the library (`lib.X86` folder) in my `Visual Studio C++` project which is configured to produce a `64-bit` `DLL`, I get the respective error and it won't build:

```
library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

<strike>Renaming the folder `lib.X86` to `lib.X64` also does not work.</strike>

How can I get it to work in a `64-bit` environment or is it not possible?

Comment: you need use 64bit libs. renaming x86 libs of course is nonsense

Comment: @RbMm: Yes but how to get them?

Comment: install sdk/wdk

Comment: @RbMm: Can you please elaborate a bit more how this enables 64-bit compilation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It seems like you have to set the target processor to 64-bit and then compile](https://github.com/Microsoft/Detours/issues/5). A working batch (`.bat`) script may be something like the following (depending on your Visual Studio installation):

```
SET DETOURS_TARGET_PROCESSOR=X64
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
NMAKE
```

With this, the `64-bit` binaries should compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, you can say

```
set DETOURS_TARGET_PROCESSOR=X64
```

and then do the `nmake` command.